# Balloon message on element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show balloon message with a title when I mouse over some element in my site. I see jQuery code but I don't know if I used it in a correct way or not.

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.balloon.js">
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready($(function() {
        $('#style1').balloon({ position: "bottom right"});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">

        <button id="style1" onclick="getValue('./CSS/style1.css')">style1</button>

    </div>
</body>
```

can you help me this link i used http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html

Comment: Is your balloon library loaded proplery? Check in devtools under "sources". Any errors in console?

Comment: you don't need jquery for this, css is enough (:hover), look here http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com , click "host a dinner" and click ok after that to get the validation baloons

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that could be wrong and some certainties.

- The balloon plugin only makes a balloon if the target element has a `title` attribute.  Your `button` doesn't.

  Make sure it has a `title` attribute.
- Make sure your js file exists at given location `./js/jquery.balloon.js` , try pressing f12 and go to the console tab and see if you spot any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add title attribute to your button

```
        <button id="style1" onclick="getValue('./CSS/style1.css')" title="Some">style1</button>
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzZ4m/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Title is missing.
<
button id="style1" onclick="getValue('./CSS/style1.css')" **title="YourTitleHere"** >

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.balloon.js">
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready($(function() {
        $('#style1').balloon({ position: "bottom right"});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
<button id="style1" onclick="getValue('./CSS/style1.css')" title="YourTitleHere">style1</button>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: One more thing: Nice balloon plugin. Thanks!

Comment: I have textbox I want when click in it popbox show with some title

Comment: my text in file.js and popbox inside script in html how can call this script from file.js

Comment: move the inside script to file.